# Spring @Value treats differently primitives and wrapper classes

Tags: java, spring

I have the following empty property in properties file:

`test.prop=`

When I try to use the property in my Spring application depending on whether I'm using primitive or wrapper class I get different results.

```
@Value("${test.prop}")
Boolean testProp = true;
```

**result**: *true*

```
@Value("${test.prop}")
boolean testProp = true;
```

**result**: *IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value []*

The similar thing with integers:

```
@Value("${test.prop}")
Integer testProp = 1;
```

**result**: *1*

```
@Value("${test.prop}")
int testProp = 1;
```

**result**: *java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""*

Questions:

- How come primitives are treated differently?
- What type is recommended to be used?
- How to set default values for empty properties?

I tried to set the default value with `${test.prop:defaultValue}` but for primitive I get the same exception and for wrapper classes I receive `null`.

Comment: My offhand guess would be that the primitives don't use the generic `ConversionService` that reference types do.

Comment: consider everything as string and format it while using.

Answer (score 3):

The "empty property" you have in your config, is actually a **present** property with an empty value `""`. This value is used in an attempted conversion to the property type. If you want to use a default value, comment out the property setting in the property file (or omit it altogether):

```
 #test.prop=
```

and use the `@Value` syntax with the default:

```
@Value("${test.prop:true}") boolean booleanProp;
```

The default is only applied when there's no value provided in the properties, not when it's empty or invalid. The code above works the same for primitives and wrappers.

Comment: It's not fully answering my questions. I know that commenting out the property would solve the problem. Can I take your answer to "How to set default values for empty properties?" as it's not possible? 
And what about  question "How come primitives are treated differently?" ?

Comment: To answer your question How come primitives are treated differently? Since the property is empty the wrapper class create a null instance, but in the case of primitive it tries to parse that values, then exception occurs.